# making a command system in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this chat room built from php html and javascript and i want users to be able to run commands that i have set in the chat room itself it a small chat room so i am not that worried about security here is what i have

```
 <?
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
 $text = $_POST['text'];

  $fp = fopen("chatLogs/defaultchatlog.html", 'a');
  fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").")<b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
 fclose($fp);
 }
 switch($text)
 {
 case '!clear!':
    //command goes here
    break;
 default:
    //code stuff

    break;
  }


   ?>
```

but this does not seem to be doing anything i was testing it out by making it direct you to another page just so i knew that it worked but it doesnt can someone please help or give me some sort of alternative

you can see my site [here](http://billischill.ddns.net)

edit

here is the code i have been messing around with but i still need help

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
$text = $_POST['text'];
switch($_POST['text'])
{
case 'MAIL':
    header('Location: http://billischill.ddns.net/mailmen.php');
    break;
case 'test':
    header('Location: http://billischill.ddns.net/testroom.php');
    break;
default:
    $fp = fopen("chatLogs/testchatlog.html", 'a');
fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").")  <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
fclose($fp);

}
?>
```

Comment: Short tags are enabled? What happens currently, any errors?

Comment: Short tags?? it just doesnt work can you please help

Comment: I can't help with just `it doesn't work`. PHP blocks open with `<?php`, not `<?` unless short tags are enabled.

Comment: see the above edit Please

Comment: U never close isset conditional

Comment: well now it posts to the chat but the command doesnt work

Comment: why is it not working it first checks the users input to see if it maches anything within the swich case statment and if it doesnt it will post it but it doesnt work right any help

Comment: Well then next question is it `POST` or `GET`? You are calling it different ways, `$text = $_POST['text'];
switch($_GET['text'])`. You should use error reporting and output through out the process to see where your script stops executing.

Comment: ok that helped a bit i changed it to POST on all of them and that seemed to get me a liitle bit farther but now when i type in the comand it wont show up on the chat but wont do anything either and its only the commands that dont show up

Comment: This question is heading down a long road. You should look into how to debug code. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you have to set a `date.timezone` in your server `php.ini` - there's a warning showing.

**Second**: your switch always goes to the `default` case. So I think you need to change the condition of the switch from `switch($_POST['text'])` to `switch($text)`. I donno why but there might be some typo or other characters in effect.

Comment: `$text = $_POST['text'];` So why would `switch($_POST['text']) to switch($text)` make a difference?  A warning wouldn't break it, also where are you seeing a warning?

Comment: (1) I don't understand it either - and I mentioned it in the answer. But it's true that it is always passed to default case. So you need to check the condition in switch. (2) warning doesn't break - `true`! But it is the date that is being printed in the `chatbox - and as you haven't set the `php.ini` value - it is showing the `UTC` time. I have seen it in `google chrome` inspector `network` tab.

Comment: im sorry but i do not seem to understand